# Get Numbered output List with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get numbered output list lets say

```
Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | out-file "C:\services.log"
```

I get all services but it is not numbered.

```
Running  AudioEndpointBu... Windows Audio Endpoint Builder        
Running  Audiosrv           Windows Audio                         
Running  BFE                Base Filtering Engine
```

How can I get numbered list like this?

```
1> Running  AudioEndpointBu... Windows Audio Endpoint Builder        
2> Running  Audiosrv           Windows Audio                         
3> Running  BFE                Base Filtering Engine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be more better if anyone need actually I need this to out-put logs while creating bulk ad users

```
$a=1;
Get-service |ForEach-Object {"$($a).) $($_.name)"; $a++} | out-file c:\services.log
```

Comment: That is good, the problem is that it's starting with `.)`, I want to make it start from `1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$global:i=0
Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Running" } | Select @{Name="Item#";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i.Tostring() + ">"}},Status,Name,Displayname | out-file "C:\services.log"
$global:i=0
```

Don't forget to reset global:i to zero (0) when done.

Found it here [PowerShell Problem Solver: Create Numbered Output Lists with PowerShell](https://www.petri.com/create-numbered-output-lists-with-powershell)

Comment: No it should have numbering like 

1>
2>
3>